# Multi Value filed Histogram on kibana 3

Tags: elasticsearch, logstash, kibana

I am facing issues while creating Histogram on kibana3.
I have to display test results as a stacked bar charts on kibana.

Ex of test Results: Passed 3 failed 5 aborted 15 
                    passed 10 failed 4 aborted 1

parsed and created value fields "passed" ,"failed" ,"aborted". Histogram graph is showing values for fields as passed 2 failed 2 aborted 2 instead of passed 13 failed 9 aborted 16.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Maybe you're doing 'count' instead of 'total'?

Comment: I tried count and total also. Total is taking one value field passed or failed or aborted but I want to graph for all three value fields.

Comment: please post the json of your dashboard, it'll help us help you.